# Swift get the remaining seconds of time on target string date

Tags: swift, date, time

The current date time today was May 9, 2020 10:03 PM, and I have a target string date with the value of `2020-05-09 22:07:30` with the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

How can I get the remaining date from that 2 date and print the value with the string of `04:30` as the range of those 2 dates are 4 `minutes and 30 seconds`

What I can only do is convert the milliseconds to time format like

```
func msToTime(ms: Int) {
    let seconds = ms % 60
    let minutes = ms / 60000

    return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d",minutes,seconds)
}
```

Output `04:30`

But I don't know how to get the range of milliseconds from today's date time to target's date time.
Or if there's any other easier way to do it?

Comment: Completely unclear. Please just state, simply and directly, the input and the desired output.

Comment: @matt my desired output was there, I have date today and target date as the given value and I want the range of two values convert to string date time (`04:30`) because it has the range of 4 minutes and 30 seconds

Comment: And the input? If I understand correctly, you have two inputs, one is a Date and the other is a String? And you want to express the difference between them in mm:ss format? Is that right?

Comment: @matt correct, but the Date input was static date of today, and the only input that was updatable was the string date (in this case it's the `2020-05-09 22:07:30`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Calendar` and `DateComponents` to easily calculate differences between dates in whatever units you desire. For example, this gets the difference in minutes and seconds:

```swift
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let date = dateformatter.date(from: "2020-05-09 22:07:30")!
let now = Date()

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: now, to: date)
print("difference: \(components.minute!):\(components.second!)")
```

Comment: Agreed; that was my first answer, but I changed it. I'm glad we've shown both ways!

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way, with no calculation of any kind needed:

```
let d1 = Date()
let s = "2020-05-09 22:07:30"
let f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
f.timeZone = TimeZone.current // or whatever
if let d2 = f.date(from: s) {
    let f = DateComponentsFormatter()
    f.unitsStyle = .positional
    let result = f.string(from: d1, to: d2)
}
```

If you don't like the resulting string format of `result`, you can eliminate pieces of it. — However, note that this works only because no full days are involved. It isn't clear what the range of possible inputs might be or what the desired output would be if the second date were three months into the future, for example.